# Running JUnit tests in Ant: why fork into separate VM?

Tags: java, ant, junit

I am relatively new to Ant and JUnit.

From reading the Ant manual and searching on Google and SO, I understand how to fork into a separate VM when running Junit tests, but not **why** this is a good or bad practice.

So far, I have found these answers:

- Running a test in a separate VM will isolate tests and prevent each test from being affected by VM-wide system properties
- Forking also allows new arguments to be passed to the VM using `<jvmarg>` [EDIT]
- Running separate VMs can slow down performance time

Is that all there is to it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you run your unit tests with a forked VM, you can pass new arguments to it. For example, you may need more memory for running your tests than for compiling, you might want to run your tests in a different directory, or maybe pass different java parameters to the new VM. If you look in the Ant manual for the [junit task](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/junit.html), you can see many of the parameters are ignored if you're not in *fork mode*.

Comment: Thanks for your reply David. It confirms what I had found on other sites. I still want to know  - apart from VM isolation, passing new arguments and performance time considerations, are there any **other** reasons for forking or not forking into a separate VM? (I have also found that a separate VM is recommended when using Cobertura.)

Comment: There is one advantage for not forking a JUnit run: Since the run is in the same VM, if a test timesout, the VM won't terminate which means that the teardown process will complete. See *Forked tests and tearDown* in the Manual page for [JUnit](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/junit.html).

Comment: One reason to fork your JUnit tests is to have a clean and independent JUnit test environment that hasn't been contaminated by requirements for Ant itself. For example, you might not want to include Ant Runtime Library in your system test. By default, each test will run in its own JVM. You can change this by setting the` forkmode` to `once`. This can be very useful if testing is taking a very long time.

Comment: You need a separate VM when you do any sort of instrumenting for code coverage. We use JaCoCo. Cobertura has had an on-and-off status for a few years. It only recently started being updated again. I like JaCoCo because JaCoCo only instruments the JUnit running rather than the compilation of the unit tests themselves.